# French long-stay student visa rejection

Tags: france, student-visa

My request for a long-stay student French visa has been refused stating: **"You pose a risk of threat of public order/ public security/ public health"**. I do not have any criminal record. I am not affected by any disease. I did do an internship at a defence organization but that was purely academic and I did get a letter from the company stating the same. But still, my visa was denied.

Apart from France, I got university admits from Sweden, the UK, Italy, etc as well. France's visa rejection is going to affect my future visa applications in these countries. I am not sure what to do. I tried mailing the embassy, but as expected no reply. I know for a fact that this decision is wrong. I heard about appealing but people said it takes a really long time and sometimes they don't even reply hence resulting in automatic rejection.

Has someone faced a similar situation? What can I do? I'd appreciate any tips and help.