# French student visa rejection

Tags: france

My request for a long-stay student French visa has been refused stating: "You pose a risk of threat of public order/ public security/ public health". I do not have any criminal record. I am not affected by any disease. I did do an internship at a defence organization but that was purely academic and I did get a letter from the company stating the same. But still, my visa was denied.

Apart from France, I got university admits from Sweden, the UK, Italy, etc as well. France's visa rejection is going to affect my future visa applications in these countries. I am not sure what to do. I tried mailing the embassy, but as expected no reply. I know for a fact that this decision is wrong. I heard about appealing but people said it takes a really long time and sometimes they don't even reply hence resulting in automatic rejection.

Has someone faced a similar situation? What can I do? I'd appreciate any tips and help.

Comment: Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/57579/schengen-visa-refusal-on-threat-to-public-policy-security-health

Comment: Yes. I've seen this question. But I am not sure if the issue was rectified or if anyone else faced this issue and got it rectified. I am just worried that this is going to affect my higher studies and possible job prospects.

Comment: The accepted answer to the linked question is also factually wrong. It is not uncommon that this reason is used to reject visa applications because of a 'near' match based on name, date of birth and other fuzzy conditions. It is usually not (if ever) based on a biometric hit as Gayot Fow and his allegedly consulted 'expert' claims. The German register consulted for such rejections did e.g. not until June 2022 include biometric data and the answer is from 2016. It is however a problem, which is not easily solved. Which country objected to the visa issuance? It should be in your rejection letter

Comment: Yeah, this does seem like a tricky problem. But I am innocent so I just want to prove my innocence. I want guidance on how to do it.

Comment: @jarnbjo it's possible that some Schengen states really do use this reason only if there's a biometric match, but that doesn't mean all do. (It's also possible that a biometric match could identify some other record really belonging to the applicant but associated with e.g. terrorist activity because of mistaken identity). Unfortunately even if the answer's reasoning is flawed, its conclusion is probably correct, namely that the best hope of rectifying the situation is to hire an immigration lawyer with experience dealing with public order/security/health rejections from that country.

Comment: "I did do an internship at a defence organization but that was purely academic and I did get a letter from the company stating the same": if they are refusing you because they believe that you are too closely associated with your country's military-industrial complex (or are simply worried that you might be) then a letter from a company that is part of that military-industrial complex isn't going to assuage their fears.  I have no idea whether this is likely to be the reason for their concern, but if it is then you will probably need to look for another way to address it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [French long-stay student visa rejection](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/26526/french-long-stay-student-visa-rejection)

Comment: "they believe that you are too closely associated with your country's military-industrial complex (or are simply worried that you might be)": but I was not associated with any of the company's ongoing projects. I had a totally separate project. " I have no idea whether this is likely to be the reason for their concern": Exactly. I've no clue what else could be the reason. But if this is the reason, what other way do you suggest to prove my innocence?